# C:How Process communicate in linux

Tags: c, linux, process

I want to count the number of processes that are created with a for 1,10 and where fork() si executed. The program is executed in linux. I really don't get how to use wait or WEXITSTATUS and I've spent hours on forums and still don't get it. Can someone help me, please?

Thanks,
Dragos

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int nr = 1;

int main()
{


    int pid;
    int i;
    int stare;
    for(i = 1; i<=10 ; i++)
    {

        pid = fork();

        if( pid !=0 )
        {

            //parent
            wait(&stare);
            nr = nr + stare;


        }
        else
        {
            //child
            nr++;
            stare = WEXITSTATUS(nr);
            exit(nr);

        }
    }

    printf("\nNr: %d\n", nr);

}
```

Comment: The `WEXITSTATUS(nr);` only makes sense for the parent. In the child process it is useless. (the child does not "see" the status (except the second child, whichh will see the status of the first child, etc)

Comment: Spend hours on forums? Why not spend minutes on a [manual page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/topic/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtpc2/cpp_wait.html#cpp_wait)?

Answer (score 1):

The macros like `WEXITSTATUS` are used in the *parent* process to get the exit status after a `wait` call.

In the child process, it's enough to just return `nr` (or call `exit` with it as argument).

In the parent you use `WEXITSTATUS` like this:

```
if (wait(&stare) > 0)
{
    if (WIFEXITED(stare))
        nr += WEXITSTATUS(stare);
}
```

We must use the `WIFEXITED` check because otherwise the exit status is not valid.

Comment: To be correct, you should only use `WEXITSTATUS` if the process exited normally (see the link in my above comment).